# How to iterate through a mysql array and append corresponding text from an PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, foreach

I am making a pricing table to upgrade membership.

In mySQL I have a table with limits on what each membership can allow [see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc0WB.png)

I grab the info from the table and try to iterate through it and append some text to it from another array. I have tried thoroughly looking online for an answer but I'm probably not even searching for the right terms. For the purpose of this question i'm using 2 fields but in reality i will be iterating and appending many columns.

Here's my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT maxProducts,maxImages FROM memproducts_membership_settings WHERE useThis='1'";

$rs = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    foreach($row as $field)
    {
        $append = array('Product Slots','Images per product');
        print $field.' '.$append.'<br>';
    }
}
```

All i get is:

5 Array

2 Array

and not what i need which would be:

5 Product Slots

2 Images per product

I'm sure there is a way to do this but i just cannot figure it out, please anyone give me some pointers? Many regards :)

Comment: There is no any "mysql array". Every array in php - is a php array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty basic stuff...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['maxProducts'] . ' Product Slots<br>';
    echo $row['maxImages'] . ' Images per product<br>';
}
```

Or if you are needing to do this with dynamic fields in whatever order you return from database like your question suggests, perhaps you might consider providing a mapping of database column names to the appropriate label content like this:

```
$labels = array(
    'maxProducts' => 'Product Slots',
    'maxImages' => 'Images per product',
    ...
);

...

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo $value . ' ' . $labels[$key] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Note if you are just learning PHP, you REALLY should NOT learn `mysql_*` functions.  They are deprecated and need to die.  Please learn to use `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Comment: I work 60 hrs a week as a taxi driver and have for the last 5 months neglected my little cms that i'm writing so i dont have to pick up idiots for a living. This answer worked for me and i truly appreciate the pointers and advice. i'll be looking into replacing the deprecated code for the newer stuff. sanitation is one subject i have considered in depth and feel i have covered but will look into it further. many many thanks

Answer (score 0):

To append values to the end of an array use array_push()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty about your code and your approach that I don't like at all, but the most immediate solution to your current problem would be to iterate the array of strings from within the `foreach` loop, using [`each()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php):

```
$strings = array('Product Slots','Images per product');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    reset($strings);
    foreach($row as $field)
    {
        $append = each($strings);
        print $field.' '.$append[1].'<br>';
    }
}
```

You should *at very least* make yourself aware of:

- the deprecation of ext/mysql (use either mysqli or PDO); and
- the risk of XSS attacks (escape any HTML in values from your database before returning them to the browser).

Answer (score 0):

It's doing what it should... You have created an array and asked it to print its name. As print can't automatically iterate an array it just tells you what the variable type is.